# NetBeans Platform: how to remove default windowing?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I am developing an application with netbeans platform and I managed to remove the default menu and toolbar, but How can I set my TopComponent as main window and disable the window management?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is well explained in Step 5 of PART 1 of below tutorial

http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-quick-start.html

Select appropriate "Window position" while component creation.

Good luck :)

Comment: ok thanks, but if I want to change it in my currect project? or I have to create a new project and add my files.

Comment: I finally created a new module configured as a editor and I copied the interface and the source code.

Comment: You need to change in layer.xml file. under tag <folder name="Windows2"> You can find position mentioned as <folder name="explorer">. Eg: change "explorer" to "output" Good luck :)